# How can I stop other plugins from using my class' sensitive methods?

Tags: security

Assume I have a Class that deals with sending sensitive user information via e-mail to the developer.

So, the whole thing would look like:

```
<?php
namespace PrivateNamespace;

class prefix_SendEmail
{
    private $developer_email = 'my_developer_email@gmail.com';

    private function prefix_sendTheEmail( $user_id )
    {
        $message = 'Some content.';
        $sensitive_information = $user->user_email;
        wp_mail( $this->developer_email, sprintf( __( 'This is an user email, very sensitive:' ), $sensitive_information ), $message );
    }
}
```

The syntax for usage is:

```
(new PrivateNamespace\prefix_SendEmail)->prefix_sendTheEmail(1);
```

It's not a singleton with a setter, matter of fact, it doesn't have a setter, regardless of it being a singleton or not. **As such, the e-mail cannot be changed.**

It's also namespaced and prefixed., so it'll avoid any name-related errors / bad calls.

So, whoever calls this class, must respect its namespace, its names (prefixed) and its rules due to the visibility of the methods.

But let's say I make the fatal mistake of creating a setter.

```
public function setEmail( $email )
{
    $this->developer_email = $email;
}
```

And this is used to set the destination of this class' routines to a possibly malicious e-mail, through another plugin that the user has installed.

In short, someone else, if the user installs their plugin, **might pull out data using my plugin's classes and methods.**

Regardless of a setter being present or not --

How would I make sure that my code can only be ran from within my plugin, given **the existence of Reflection Classes that can just mock my classes and modify them**?

Simply trusting the users to not install plugins that mess with my classes is not enough.

Comment: If a malicious plugin is installed, you can't do anything, the game has already been lost. Any PHP safeguards you put in place can be eliminated by simply copying the file and modifying it. Having said that, the chances of your classes being meddled with are fantastically tiny. They could even serialize the object or use functions such as `var_export` etc. If they are meddled with, it's likely to be a developer frustrated that you didn't provide an API to do what the client asked

Comment: @TomJNowell Understandable, I was just wondering if there's any cases / angles I'm missing.